# How can I expand my root partition on kali linux?

Tags: partition, kali-linux, gparted

I need some space on my root partition that is getting full, so I used GParted to getting some space as unallocated.

[image: gparted 1]

Now I want to expand the `/dev/sdb1` but when I click to resize the buttons are not enabled and there is no option to expand it.

[image: gparted 2]

How can I solve this?

I am not using LVM and would love an alternative that does not include starting over.

Comment: Welcome to the the Unix and Linux stack exchange! Please review the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to get information on how to best post to the site. Take the [Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) if you are not familiar with how this site works. To get to your question, are you using LVM? If not, it will likely be easier and faster to start over with an lvm setup and partition sizes more appropriately sized. Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/529668/edit) your post to include these details. Thank you!

Comment: @kemotep sadly not using LVM and starting over the installation is my last option for now.

Comment: Could it be that you are running Kali Linux from the same partition you are trying to re-size?

Comment: @PierreB actually no, I tried it using a live boot

Comment: According to these pictures, there's no contiguous free space after the sdb1, hence you can't grow it.

Comment: You make be able to move the other partitions first, or move the root. Or move some stuff from the root to another partition and symlink / mount it. I would move the root to the end, extend it to 20GB. Extend the extended partition down, move the 3 small partitions down, and expand /home down. This would leave a big gap between /home and / (so it is easier next time). **However and this is a big however, how can you use 11GB of root on kali? I am using that much in Debian, and I have Latex and the manuals installed, and a load of docker images, and containers. Kali ≠ a general purpose OS**

Comment: shrink `sdb2` first, then expand preceeding space

Comment: If you can identify the directory consuming the most storage, you can move those files to a separate partition and mount the filesystem where said files are expected to be. You can start the analysis like this: `du -hx / > /tmp/filesizes.txt`